# AS3: how to find out the number of connected users in the net group?

Tags: actionscript-3, p2p, adobe-cirrus

I'd like to get the number of users connected to my net group. Not just my peers/neighbors, but all the clients within the group. Does Cirrus provide such functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a property you can read:

```
NetGroup.estimatedMemberCount
```

That one tells you the estimate of all connections in the NetGroup.  It's only an estimate based on neighbors you are connected to ... and they are connected to .. neighbor density... etc.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. I hoped there's some way to find out the exact number of net group members... Since the Cirrus handle all the logic for the NetGroup, it should be able to count the members easily. But for some reason it's not implemented.

Comment: From Adobe's site: "This property is based on the neighbor density in the numeric region, also called a group address, closest to the peer. As peers connect and disconnect from the mesh the estimatedMemberCount is not guaranteed to change. However, it often will increment and decrement, providing a rough estimate on the number of members in the P2P group."

Comment: @JasonReeves thanks this works great for me, i wanted to ask i have checked the NetGroup properties is there something like this to list all the active groups when you set a name in the GroupSpecifier?